# Texture just wraps around arm rather than the whole shirt

Tags: texturing

I'm currently following Amelylina's video tutorial and I'm down to the last step of texturing. All has gone well until now. I'll have images attached to show what I'm talking about. When I go into either rendered mode or material mode or heck even solid mode it goes a dark grey and then the texture just wraps around a sleeve. Am I missing something? I've also attached a picture of hers showing what it should do.

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hard to tell. Is the UV map ok? Is there another object in the same spot?

Comment: Blunder, I added a picture of the uv_1 and uv_0 maps hopefully that'll help tell ya what I've done wrong. Thank you

Comment: Hm, You have 2 UV maps? uv_0 looks ok (2nd screenshot) but uv_1 looks a bit strange overlapping vertices? Looks like there are seams missing. Which UV map do you use in the material? (I am not that familiar with Blender 2.79. Is there a reason why you use this old version and not the 2.83 LTS?)